# Invalid rule reference error when compiling Windows Speech Recognition Macros

Tags: javascript, xml, speech-recognition

Lately I have gotten interested in trying out some XML and Javascript with Windows Speech Recognition Macros. This is my first experience with both languages, but since I do have a small programming history, I thought that I could just dive in. And so far it has gone pretty well. But now that I am trying to implement a deeper level of interactivity to my macros I start running into errors of which I can find no explaination online, so I came here to ask for your help.

This is the macro that is giving me problems:

```
<command>
    <listenFor>Whats the weather like in [CityName]</listenFor>
    <script language="JScript">
        <![CDATA[
            var xml_doc = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");
            xml_doc.async = false;
            xml_doc.load("http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q={[CityName]}&mode=xml");

            var city = xml_doc.getElementByTagName("city").getAttribute("name");
            var temperature = xml_doc.getElementByTagName("temperature");

            Application.Speak(city);
        ]]>
    </script>
</command>
```

And this is the error message:

```
Error compiling grammar for speech Macros:
"AI-base.WSRMac"
==========
Line 40: 80045048 - Invalid rule reference to <RULEREF NAME="CityName" REFID=""/>
==========
00001:
00002: <GRAMMAR LANGID="0409">
...
...
...
00038: <RULE NAME="Rule_8">
00039:  <P>
00040:   <p>Whats the weather like in </p><ruleref name="CityName" propname="CityName" />
00041:  </P>
00042: </RULE>
00043: <RULE name="build:namedDictation"><dictation min="1" max="10"/></RULE>
00044: </GRAMMAR>
```

What I am trying to do with this macro is get a cityname from the user and get the weather for that location, out it in a couple of variables and then let it tell me the weather in a format I like.

Could someone please explain what I am doing wrong and how to fix it?

Thanks in advance :)
-Dirk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, WSR Macros doesn't have a predefined 'CityName' property.  The examples I've seen that use 'CityName' define a list of named cities with the appropriate properties.  For example, the Weather.WSRMac sample has

```
<listenForList name="CityName" propname="zipCode"> 
    <item propval="45255">Cincinnati</item> 
    <item propval="98075">Sammamish</item> 
    <item propval="98052">Redmond</item> 
    <item propval="98004">Bellevue</item> 
    <item propval="98101">Seattle</item> 
</listenForList>
```

You would need to do something similar.

If you need an uninterpreted string, you could try

```
 <rule name="CityName">
      <Dictation PROPID="Dictation" Min="1" Max="5"/>
 </rule>
```

To retrieve the content at runtime, you should be able to use

```
 xml_doc.load("http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q={[CityName.Dictation]}&mode=xml");
```

Almost all of this is available on the [WSR Macros Wiki](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/wsrmacros/Wiki/View.aspx?title=Windows%20Speech%20Recognition%20Macros%20Wiki), particularly the section on [Rule Generators](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/wsrmacros/Wiki/View.aspx?title=Rule%20Generators&referringTitle=Windows%20Speech%20Recognition%20Macros%20Wiki); the details on SAPI 5 XML grammars are also on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms723634%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: Then how do I put the cityname in something like a variable without using that?

Comment: Edited answer to demonstrate how to embed a dictation rule.

Comment: I have one more question regarding this, which is how I then use the rule in javascript, because it is giving me an error saying: "Object doesn't support this property or method" at this line: `xml_doc.load("http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q={[Spoken.CityName]}&mode=xml");`

Comment: You need to add a PROPID attribute to the dictation tag, and then you should be able to retrieve the dictation contents.  Updated answer to illustrate.

Comment: Thank you very much again. I am not able to test it right now since i am in a silenced room, but I will as soon as possible.